# Livecode: Detect cursor position inside the field

Tags: livecode

Is there a way to detect if the user has move the cursor somewhere in the field?

Looks like the field does not trigger any `mouseDown` or `mouseUp` event when I click the edit field.

Also, can we return the position of the cursor inside the field when the user click inside the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `selectionChanged` message to detect changes in the cursor position. Use `openField` to find out when the user clicks in an unlocked field. `The selectedChunk` tells you exactly where the cursor is. If no text is selected, the first number in `the selectedChunk` is higher than the last number. If text is selected, the first number is lower than the second, e.g. `char 3 to 10 of field 1`.